# Is it possible to treat | as text instead of a filter?

Tags: liquid

I have a variable which dumps some comments from my site

{{ comment_variable }}

However the comments often contain the pipe symbol, because the users commenting have responded in multiple languages and used that symbol to separate.

eg. Hello | Bonjour

When I try to return this variable in my email template, it says

Hello

because the pipe symbol assumes that Bonjour is a filter function.

Is there any way to return the entire string as text? or will I have to do a bulk replace in the db?

I tried to assign variable and return as raw

Hello, Mr. X - here are the comments that you got on your entry.

{{ comment_variable }}

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be wanting the [escape filter](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/escape/).

An example would be:

```
{{ comment_variable | escape }}
```

Although, it makes me think there is an issue a bit deeper on how you obtain this variable. I was playing around in a [liquid sandbox](https://jumpseller.com/support/liquid-sandbox/) with both `capture` and `assign` of `hello | world` and it kept outputting what I expected - `hello | world`.